# Suggested reading order for the Battletech Mechwarrior novels?

Tags: suggested-order, battletech

I have been playing alot of Mech Warrior Online recently, and it's bringing back quite a bit of nostalgia for some of the older games in the franchise I used to play.  Because the developers for MWO seem to be trying their hardest to keep the game's timeline and major events/developments in line with the official Battletech canon for the chosen timeframe, I've been getting a decent ammount of engaging lore.

I want more.  I would love to read some of the MechWarrior books, but I haven't the slightest clue where to start with them.

does anyone have a good order to begin them in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start at the beginning. [Here's a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_BattleTech_novels) to a list of books. I started with the Robert Thurston trilogy. They are fairly good. Good luck in your choice, and hope you enjoy them.